# Monte Carlo Pricing of Barrier Options - can't figure out where I'm wrong

Tags: option-pricing, programming, homework

I'm trying to price a simple Up-and-out Barrier option using Monte Carlo; haven't even implemented the variance reduction but it's already glitching.

The code seems right, but I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

```
nsims = 100000
discrete_freq = 252
S0 = 50
sig = .3
r = .05
K = 60
T = .25
H = 55
```

```
# simulates GBM paths
def simulate_gbm_paths(nsims, S0, sig, mu, T, discrete_freq):
    '''
    nsims: number of simulations to produce
    S0: initial stock price
    sig: volatility expressed as a percentage
    mu: annualized drift expressed as a percentage
    r: interest rate
    T: time in years
    discrete_freq: number of discrete time intervals per increment of T (252 would be 1 trading year)
    '''
    nparts = int(T)*discrete_freq + int(discrete_freq * (T - np.floor(T)))
    dt = T / nparts
    Xt = np.log(S0) + np.cumsum(( (mu - sig**2/2)*dt + sig*np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.normal(size=(nparts,nsims)) ), axis=0)
    Xt = np.exp(Xt)
    Xt = np.vstack([np.repeat(S0, nsims), Xt])

    return Xt

def barrier_option_pricing_monte_carlo(nsims, S0, sig, r, T, discrete_freq, H, optype = "uop"):
    gbm_sim = simulate_gbm_paths(nsims, S0, sig, r, T, discrete_freq)
    max_array = np.max(gbm_sim, axis=0)
    if optype == "uop":            
        return np.exp(-r*T) * np.sum((np.maximum(K - gbm_sim[-1], 0) * (max_array < H)*1)) * 1/nsims
```

```
barrier_option_pricing_monte_carlo(nsims, S0, sig, r, T, discrete_freq, H, optype="uop")
```

```
# 7.352723976215193
# real pricing according to closed form solution: $ 6.869
```

I've been staring at this for a while, and I can't figure out how it's wrong. I appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks

Comment: Does the closed form solution assume a continuous barrier? If so I would check if the MC price gets closer when you increase the `discrete_freq`.

Comment: @KurtG. Ah yes, thanks! Apparently, barrier option pricing has very high bias without small increments. I increased the freq to 8500 and that did the trick. I'll try speeding it up using variance reduction methods.

Comment: Great. The good thing is that your MC price `7.3527` was larger than the closed form price `6.869` because a discretely monitored barrier has a lower probability of knocking the option out. This [paper](http://www.columbia.edu/~sk75/mfBGK.pdf) treats the subject in a more elaborate way.